# Enable docker registry mirror ( nexus ) on EKS nodes

Tags: docker, amazon-eks

Im trying to configue eks node pools to spinup nodes that will be configured to use docker registry mirror (sonatype nexus cache repo in my case) ,
I know i have 2 options, 1 to use custom ami ( not in favor of that option of course) and 2 to configure user—data for the launch template to change the dockerd configuration and restart it.

I tried that by doing the following :

`#!/bin/bash cat <<EOF >/etc/docker/daemon.json {"registry-mirrors": "http://nexus.xxxxxxx.com:9091”} EOF systemctl restart docker --no-block` 
That didn't work,
If anyone have a good advice on nice example for the user data for eks